# Hive variables with where condition

Tags: variables, hive, conditional-statements

I create a query variables with where condition

```
set Source_record= 'select count(1), batch_id from customer 
where customer_type = 'Retail' group by batch_id’ ;
```

I get error message

> “Syntax error, found: '=' at line 1,”

Is something wrong with where conditions?

Comment: hive is not the same with mysql. look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988960/storing-query-result-in-a-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing query result in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988960/storing-query-result-in-a-variable)