# assign date value dynamically to hive query

Tags: hive

I have partitioned table in hive and I want to assign value for date column dynamically( yesterday's date ). Below is my current query but it's not working.

```
ALTER TABLE db1.table1 ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (loaddate="date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') , 1)") LOCATION "hdfs://location1/abc/rawdata/externalhivetables/downloading/data";
```

Instead of returning the date value it's returning me the complete expression.

```
select downloading.loaddate From downloading limit 3;

+------------------------------------------------------------+
 |              downloading.loaddate                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') , 1) |
| date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') , 1) |
| date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') , 1) |
```

Answer (score 0):

In hive shell we cannot assign **`variable variables from the result of query`** yet, we need to have 2 steps:

Use **`Shell script`** to execute the query and store the result into a `variable`.

Then initialize the **`hive shell/script`** with the variable.

```
bash$ var=`hive -S -e "select date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') , 1);"`
bash$ echo $var
```

Now initialize **`hive/beeline`** shell with the `var`value

```
bash$ hive -hiveconf dd=$var

hive> ALTER TABLE db1.table1 ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (loaddate='${hiveconf:dd}') LOCATION "hdfs://location1/abc/rawdata/externalhivetables/downloading/data";
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988960/storing-query-result-in-a-variable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts) links for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Use shell to calculate date and substitute it using shell variable substitution:

```
bash$ dt=$(date -d '-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d)
bash$ hive -e "ALTER TABLE db1.table1 ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (loaddate='$dt') LOCATION 'hdfs://location1/abc/rawdata/externalhivetables/downloading/data'"
```